# How is interactive content inside `dt` elements exposed to the accessibility tree?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Putting a link inside a `dt` element is valid HTML. The [first website](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html) even does so.

```
<dl>
<dt><a>My Link</a></dt>
<dd>Info about link</dd>
</dl>
```

However, I know there can be accessibility problems if you put interactive content inside a `summary` element because many browsers expose this element as something like a button.

I think at least in earlier standards `dt` could be exposed as a `term` role which should not have interactive content like a link inside.

Should I put interactive content inside `dt` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood the warnings in ARIAI 1.1
.

You can put interactive content **inside** [dt](https://w3c.github.io/html-aam/#el-dt) or [dd](https://w3c.github.io/html-aam/#el-dd) elements. These elements themselves are exposed as [term](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#term) or [definition](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#definition) roles in the browser accessibility tree.

The problem is with setting interactive content itself to term or definition roles.

So basically `<span role="definition"><a>My Link</a></span>` is ok if a little silly. But `<a role="definition">My Link</a>` is wrong bad.